# How to use the Dir command to create a list.txt file of all files in all subdirectories which does *not* include the pathnames

Tags: batch-file, directory, command

sI have a large directory of photos which are already sorted into subfolders for which I need to create an inventory list.

**I am currently using this command**

```
dir /s /b /a-d >_list-photos.txt
```

I want a list of just the filenames, **not** the subdirectories prefixed in the path.

**Currently I get this:**

```
D:\Engagement\The happy couple.jpg
D:\Wedding\Still in love.jpg
D:\Divorce\Not so happy.jpg
```

**What I want is this:**

```
The happy couple.jpg
Still in love.jpg
Not so happy.jpg
```

Your advice appreciated!

Comment: for /r "C:\My jpgs\" %%a in (*) do echo %%~nxa)>"_list-photos.txt"`

Comment: That works a treat - thanks @Stephan

Comment: Also, you could use the same `dir` command, but within a `for /f` loop instead: `@(for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /s /b /a-d') do @echo %%~nxa)>"_list-photos.txt"`